# Is it possible to terminate a promise's code block from another promise?

Tags: concurrency, promise, raku

I wrote this test program:

```
await Promise.anyof(
  Promise.allof((^5).map: {start { sleep 10; say "done $_" } }),
  Promise.in(5).then: { say 'ouch' }
);
sleep 10;
```

When the second promise times out it prints 'ouch' and the await exits, but the first promise's code block is still running. After five more seconds its five processes end and print 'done':

```
$ ./test1.p6
ouch
done 0
done 1
done 2
done 3
done 4
```

I tried to terminate the first promise assigning it to a variable and then calling the `.break` method from the second promise, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to kill the first promise and the other five sub-promises it started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to somehow tell the process that it doesn't have to finish.

```perl6
my $cancel = Cancellation.new;

await Promise.anyof(
  Promise.allof(
    (^5).map: {
      last if $cancel.cancelled;

      start {
        sleep 10;
        say "done $_" unless $cancel.cancelled
      }
    }
  ),
  Promise.in(5).then: {
    $cancel.cancel;
    say 'ouch'
  }
);
```

---

If you want something like `Promise.in()` that can be cancelled, let's start by [looking at the existing code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/74687ae5cf13bad24eac515500dc670b143d602a/src/core/Promise.pm6#L252-L257).

```perl6
method in(Promise:U: $seconds, :$scheduler = $*SCHEDULER) {
    my $p   := self.new(:$scheduler);
    my $vow := $p.vow;
    $scheduler.cue({ $vow.keep(True) }, :in($seconds));
    $p
}
```

Note that the result of `$scheduler.cue` is a Cancellation.

I am just going to wrap a Promise, and a Cancellation in a class for simplicity.
(I don't want to reimplement every method).

```perl6
class Cancellable-Timer {
    has Promise      $.Promise;
    has              $!vow;
    has Cancellation $!cancel;

    method !SET-SELF ( $!promise, $!vow, $!cancel ){
        self
    }

    method in (::?CLASS:U: $seconds, :$scheduler = $*SCHEDULER) {
        my $p   := Promise.new(:$scheduler);
        my $vow := $p.vow;
        my $cancel = $scheduler.cue({ $vow.keep(True) }, :in($seconds));
        self.bless!SET-SELF($p,$vow,$cancel);
    }

    method cancel ( --> Nil ) {
        # potential concurrency problem
        if $!Promise.status == Planned {
            $!cancel.cancel;          # cancel the timer
            $!vow.break("cancelled"); # break the Promise
        }
    }

    method cancelled () {
        # Ignore any concurrency problems by using the Promise
        # as the sole source of truth.
        $!Promise.status ~~ PromiseStatus::Broken
    }
}

my $timer = Cancellable-Timer.in(1);
my $say = $timer.Promise.then: *.say;
Promise.in(0.1).then: {$timer.cancel};
await $say;
```

Note that the above class is just a rough first draft.

Comment: There's a way to cancel the Promise.in()? (Changing `Promise.in(5)` into `Promise.in(15)` shows that its execution goes on after exiting the `await`; one can write `say 'ouch' unless $cancel.cancelled` but the timeout process still runs)

Comment: @FernandoSantagata `Promise.in` just does [`$scheduler.cue({ $vow.keep(True) }, :in($seconds))`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/74687ae5cf13bad24eac515500dc670b143d602a/src/core/Promise.pm6#L252-L257).

Comment: @FernandoSantagata I just added code that would do that.

Answer (score 3):

Try with ***whenever***:

```
$ perl6 -e '

react {
   for ^5 -> $num {
      whenever start { sleep 10 } {
         say "done $num"
      }
   }
   whenever Promise.in: 5 {
      say "ouch";
      done
   }
}

' ouch
```

Comment: At first I actually tried to use a react block, but the program was slightly more complex and the react block didn't work.
Since it's not possible to add formatted code in a comment, here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/wzxscNWx
It works as expected when one leaves that part of the code commented, but if one de-comments it, strangely the code runs for the entire 10 second interval; I can't explain why.