# How to kill a thread, stop a promise execution in Raku

Tags: asynchronous, raku

I am looking for a wait to stop (send an exception) to a running promise on `SIGINT`. The examples given in the [doc](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/signal#(Supply)_sub_signal) exit the whole process and not just one worker.

Does someone know how to "kill", "unschedule", "stop" a running thread ?

This is for a [p6-jupyter-kernel](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel/issues/75) issue or this [REPL issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/be7ce041a800a9b3f4b532b84583ce0c8b42eec0/src/core/REPL.pm#L374).

Current solution is restarting the repl but not killing the blocked thread

```
await Promise.anyof(
  start {
      ENTER $running = True;
      LEAVE $running = False;
      CATCH {
          say $_;
          reset;
      }
      $output :=
        self.repl-eval($code,:outer_ctx($!save_ctx),|%adverbs);
  },
  $ctrl-c
);
```

Comment: On Liz's answer you write "like [`pthread_cancel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)." The linked doc begins "send a cancellation request to a thread" and describes cooperative cancellation. Raku already has cooperative [`Cancellation`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Cancellation). That's what Brad shows in [his answer to **Is it possible to terminate a promise's code block from another promise?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52956311/1077672) and is presumably what Liz meant by "A thread can check a flag every so often, and decide to call it quits if that flag is set."

Comment: I've no idea if the following is relevant to your situation but... I found [an answer related to cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095841/1077672) that Jonathan posted a few weeks ago. In it he wrote "look at using the `Supply` paradigm instead, where there is a cancellation model (closing the tap)". And he wrote "when we have some kind of `Promise` cancellation provisions in core" in a comment he added below the answer. To be clear, this was written relative to a very different context, but it seems to me like some of the info he provided could well be relevant to your scenario.

Comment: Tk @raiph, I did not see those post. I tested them, and they prevent the code from being executed (`Cancelation`) or stop waiting (closing `tap`) but do not stop some background execution. I'll search for a way to ask kindly a thread to check `bool-must-die` from time to time

Comment: Well I forgot to precise (important) that the code running in the thread is not in my hand. It belongs to the user of the repl. But still, you are right that the check `.cancelled` is the way to do. I must still detour the "client" thread from time to time to check it.

Comment: "discuss this with Jonathan before investing significant effort" -> I sent him an email. He is definitely the best to give me a way. I guess a little work in low level is the only way. Some testing in high level must come with it. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version: don't use threads for this, use processes. Killing the running process probably is the best thing that can be achieved in this situation in general.

Long answer: first, it's helpful to clear up a little confusion in the question.

First of all, there's no such thing as a "running `Promise`"; a `Promise` is a data structure for conveying a result of an asynchronous operation. A `start` block is really doing three things:

1. Creating a `Promise` (which it evaluates to)
2. Scheduling some code to run
3. Arranging that the outcome of running that code is reflected by keeping or breaking the `Promise`

That may sound a little academic, but really matters: a `Promise` has no awareness of what will ultimately end up keeping or breaking it.

Second, a `start` block is not - at least with the built-in scheduler - backed by a thread, but rather runs on the thread pool. Even if you could figure out a way to "take out" the thread, the thread pool scheduler is not going to be happy with having one of the threads it expects to eat from the work queue on disappear. You could write your own scheduler that really does back work with a fresh thread each time, but that still isn't a complete solution: what if the piece of code the user has requested execution of schedules work of its own, and then `await`s that? Then there is no one thread to kill to really bring things to a halt.

Let's assume, however, that we did manage to solve all of this, and we get ourselves a list of one or more threads that we really want to kill without their cooperation (cooperative situations are fairly easy; we use a `Promise` and have code poll that every so often and `die` if that cancellation `Promise` is ever kept/broken).

Any such mechanism that wants to be able to stop a thread blocked on anything (not just compute, but also I/O, locking, etc.) would need deep integration and cooperation from the underlying runtime (such as MoarVM). For example, trying to cancel a thread that is currently performing garbage collection will be a disaster (most likely deadlocking the VM as a whole). Other unfortunate cancellation times could lead to memory corruption if it was half way through an operation that is not safe to interrupt, deadlocks elsewhere if the killed thread was holding locks, and so forth. Thus one would need some kind of safe-pointing mechanism. (We already have things along those lines in MoarVM to know when it's safe to GC, however cancellation implies different demands. It probably cross-cuts numerous parts of the VM codebase.)

And that's not all: the same situation repeats at the Raku language level too. `Lock::Async`, for example, is not a kind of lock that the underlying runtime is aware of. Probably the best one can do is try to tear down the callstack and run all of the `LEAVE` phasers; that way there's some hope (if folks used the `.protect` method; if they just called `lock` and `unlock` explicitly, we're done for). But even if we manage not to leak resources (already a big ask), we still don't know - in general - if the code we killed has left the world in any kind of consistent state. In a REPL context this could lead to dubious outcomes in follow-up executions that access the same global state. That's probably annoying, but what really frightens me is folks using such a cancellation mechanism in a production system - which they will if we implement it.

So, effectively, implementing such a feature would entail doing a significant amount of difficult work on the runtime and Rakudo itself, and the result would be a huge footgun (I've not even enumerated all the things that could go wrong, just the first few that came to mind). By contrast, killing a process clears up all resources, and a process has its own memory space, so there's no consistency worries either.

Comment: Well, I think this definitely answer the question.
I understand why no shotgun to kill anything anyhow. I also hate dangerous weapons. So no generic way to solve this thread stop (no high level language do it).
So (I hold on), let me argue for a specific way for stoping the blocked `REPL` loop. As `SIGINT` is already very dangerous (kill all if not catched), it could be catched asynchronously, see other comment.

Comment: In python, they catch `SIGINT` specifically in the main thread `KeyboardInterrupt` and can resent it to a `try` `catch`. Which is pretty close to the `signal.tap` declaration in perl except that this is synchronously trigger with a `lock acquire` in [Modules/_threadmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_threadmodule.c#L48-L81). So this lead to my other comment.

Comment: Maybe I can solve my issue without hiring your low level skills to change the underworld. I asked `how to kill a thread` (bad guy). But you may think it differently if I ask `how to detour a thread (to death)` (better). Is it possible with a lock to run synchrounously some code when the lock is acquire ? (I'm no async expert) -> I know you can lock code with a lock. But can you unlock code even when running some other code with an other type of lock. Then `detour your flow` from `other thread` order. Thanks @jonathan-worthington (I love your slides, and stop harassing you [for today] :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no way to stop a thread if it doesn't want to be stopped.

A thread can check a flag every so often, and decide to call it quits if that flag is set.  It would be very nice if we would have a way to throw an exception inside a thread from another thread.  But we do not, at least not as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Liz, Thanks for your fast reply. It would be very nice effectively like [pthread_cancel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html). I'll have a look but this is lowww level stuff.

Comment: if you look into this, you would have to do that through libuv, as that's the abstraction that MoarVM uses.  Or leave it as a suggestion at https://grants.perlfoundation.org